# IIS Setting Response header makes loading site very slow

Tags: iis, asp.net, http-headers, iis-8.5, asp.net-mvc

My site loads very slow. I have enabled Failed Request Tracing to trace status 200 pages. When I view the trace, I notice that following setting the response header takes a long time:

> GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER HeaderName="X-AspNetMvc-Version", HeaderValue="5.1", Replace="false" **17:06:20.608**
>
> GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER HeaderName="X-Frame-Options", HeaderValue="SAMEORIGIN", Replace="false" **17:06:23.686**
>
> GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER HeaderName="Cache-Control", HeaderValue="private", Replace="true" **17:06:44.826**

Can someone explain what is going on here? And how to fix this?

I am running a 4.5.1 application on IIS 8.5

Comment: static iisstart.htm give the same latency ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 No that one goes fine

Comment: @Martijn Did you ever get clarity on this? I'm seeing something similar.